# Как сделать ленту

Tags: css

[image: ribbon]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как сделать вот такие блоки ?

Comment: Нужно использовать псевдо классы в css: `::before`, `::after`

Comment: В дополнении к ответу выше, вы можете присмотреться к какому-нибудь css фреймворку. Например в *semantic*, подобные вещи уже реализованы. [**Вот примеры**](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/label.html)